# Entity Parameter on Invoke not generating on client

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have a simple [Invoke] method that has a class as a wrapper, see below.  The problem is the FirstOne property does not show up in the ComplexObject on the client-side.

I can work around this by making the FirstOne property a property of the Invoke method and it works fine.

What would cause this to not generate on the client?

```
public class MyRequest 
{
    public ParentEntity FirstOne { get; set; }
    public int SecondOne { get; set; }
}

[Invoke]
public void DoIt(MyRequest req)
{
    // blah
}
```

Comment: I switched to just using a .shared validation scheme using DataAnnotations.

Comment: I ended up just writing a quick TryValidateWarnings method since what I needed was not just ValidationErrors but Warnings as well.  I split the 2 and showed them both together as a popup for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an Invoke statement, you can only use simple types (int, double, float, etc.)  Complex types are not allowed when using the Invoke command.

See Colin Blair response [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/160586/360514.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  I needed to fix my solution before I could test with different entities.